# Time-zone Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can somebody recommend how to get a current time/date in a specific timezone ?

This is what I got so far:

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let str = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)


dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as! TimeZone

print(str)
```

It gives me my current time, I'm not sure how to change timezone correctly so it would print time in a specified time-zone...

Comment: you need to set the timezone before getting the string from your date

Comment: @LeoDabus can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: set `dateFormatter.timeZone = ..` before `dateFormatter.string(...)`. `NSDate` or `Date` object doesn't have any timezone information. It is just a UTC time object.

Comment: Btw You are supposed to use `Date` instead of `NSDate` and `TimeZone(identifier:)` instead of `NSTimeZone`

Comment: works now thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68990368/16023958 Here is one shortcut way to do it. Hope it helps you.